# Is $F^F$ a subspace of $F^{\infty}$ where $F$ is a field?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is $F^F$ a subspace of $F^{\infty}$ where $F$ is a field?

I am trying to prove that $F^\infty$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space by showing that its subspace is not finite-dimensional. I know that $\mathcal{P}(F)$ is infinite-dimensional and I also know that $\mathcal{P}(F)$ is a subspace of $F^F$. Hence it would be to sufficient to show that $F^{\infty}$ is infinite-dimensional if $F^F$ is a subspace of it. I am kind of new to these kinds of proofs, and I am a little fuzzy with the intuition behind $F^F$ and $F^\infty$, so I am stuck with my proof at this point.

Note that $\mathcal{P}(F)$ is the set of all polynomials.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What even is $F^\infty$?

Comment: thanks Jose, I edited my question

Comment: $F^\infty$ is the the set of all infinite lists (vectors) formally.

Comment: What is the vector space structure you put on $\mathcal P(F)$?

Comment: It is the set of all polynomials.

Comment: @BalaramBehera: Then you should write that in your question; I read it as the power set.

Comment: just did it, thanks

Comment: BTW, if your goal is to show that $F^\infty$ has infinite dimension, all you need to do is to show an infinite linear independent set, which is rather simple. Only if you want to tell the exact dimension you have to do more work. Alternatively, showing an injection from the space of polynomials into $F^\infty$ is also not hard.

Comment: thanks for the ideas, i'll do some more work and come back if I get stuck again. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is more than one "infinity", so let's fix an infinite set $I$ and talk about $F^I$ rather than $F^\infty$.

The easiest way to show that $F^I$ is infinite dimensional is to exhibit an infinite linearly independent family of vectors. Consider e.g. the family of vectors $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ defined as follows: the $i^\textrm{th}$ component of $e_i$ is $1$, all other components are $0$. In other words, if you write $e_i= (e_i^j)_{j \in I}$ then $e_i^j = \delta_{i, j}$ where $\delta_{i, j}$ is the Krönecker symbol.

All you have to do is to show that the family $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ is **linearly independent**, ie that whenever one considers pairwise distinct $i_1,\dots, i_n \in I$  and $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \in F$ satisfying $\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k e_{i_k} = 0$, then all $\lambda_k$s are equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, $F^F$ is not a subspace of $F^\infty=F^\mathbb N$.

A simple example is $F=\mathbb R$. This is a set of cardinality $2^{\mathfrak c}$, where $\mathfrak c$ is the cardinality of $\mathbb R$, while $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$ has only cardinality $\mathfrak c$. Clearly a subspace cannot be larger than the full space.

Indeed, $F^F$ is (isomorphic to) a subspace of $F^\mathbb N$ iff $F$ is countable (that is, either finite or equinumerous to the natural numbers).